# How to disable a malicious kick off service

Tags: ssh, login, who

I'm using a Linux server with my whole team together. We all have sudo permission.

As we know, we can kick someone off easily: `who -u` will list all of ssh logins with their PIDs and then `kill -9` anyone.

Now let's say some bad man wrote a bash script, which would loop all of login users and kick off all of them:

```
while true
do
    # kill -9 each PID in `who -u`
done
```

Also, the bad man configured the bash script with systemd so that it would be started automatically while booting or rebooting.

Now, I think nobody could remote login anymore.

My question is if there is some technique to solove this problem without reinstalling the OS.

Comment: You could boot a live system and delete the systemd unit

Comment: If you know the systemd unit's name, you could run `ssh hostname sudo systemctl stop unitname ; sudo systemctl disable unitname`.   If you don't know the unit's name, you *might* be able to find it with `ssh hostname systemctl  list-unit-files | cat` (the cat is to prevent it from piping the output into less).

Comment: @cas  Nice, this could be belpful.

Comment: `ssh hostname systemctl list-unit-files | cat` runs `systemctl list-unit-files` remotely, but `cat` locally. You could omit the `| cat` part entirely, and the remote `systemctl` will still detect that the command is not running on a TTY and will skip the pager because of that. (Unless you've made `ssh -t` the default for all your SSH invocations, that is.)

Comment: yes, i forgot to wrap quotes around the commands.   everything after the `ssh hostname` should be in quotes - on both of the ssh commands i gave.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a clean reinstall.

Sure, you can reboot from another source (rescue/life CD), and you can disable the systemd unit.

But how do you even know that it is a systemd unit if you can't login? How do you know it is the script you posted?

And the most important point, how do you know there are no other modifications? There may be some traps hidden that are much less obvious.

Comment: You are reasonable. What I'm considering is that there is nothing more but just a kick-off-users script. That's all, no other traps. I know that there are so much hacker techniques. But for now, isn't there any simple way to fix such a simple stuff except reinstalling?

Comment: Boot from a life CD and remove that script. If it is a hosted server, most hosting services have a way to boot a rescue system.